# what is the different between pandas_udf from Pyspark and to_pandas?

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions

When I clean big data by pandas, I have two methods：one method is to use `@pandas_udf` from `pyspark 2.3+` clean data，another is to convert `sdf` to `pdf` by `toPandas()` ,and then use pandas to clean.
I'm confused what are these methods different?

I hope helper could explain from distributed, speed and other directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `@pandas_udf` and `toPandas` are very different;

`@pandas_udf`

> Creates a vectorized user defined function (UDF).

which leverages the vectorization feature of pandas and serves as a faster alternative for `udf`, and it works on ***distributed dataset***; To learn more about the `pandas_udf` performance, you can read [pandas_udf vs udf performance benchmark here](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html).

While `toPandas` collect the distributed spark data frame as pandas data frame, pandas data frame is ***localized***, and resides in driver's memory so:

> this method should only be used if the resulting Pandas’s DataFrame is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver’s
>   memory.

So if your data is large, then you can't use `toPandas`; `@pandas_udf` or `udf` or other built in methods would be your only option;

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.So I wonder if i can understand that pandas_udf  use pandas API to process the distributed data set, and toPandas() turns the distributed data set into local data and then use pandas for processing?

Comment: Basically that's how I understand it ~